# Change Logback logging in Play standalone

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

When I create a Scala Play `web` application, Play generates a `conf/logback.xml` file that allows me to configure how the application logs.

I created a Scala Play `standalone` application and when I include Slick statements I get the following in the console:

```
21:46:04.811 [AsyncExecutor.default-16] DEBUG slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement - Preparing statement: insert into report_data (cert,repdte,p3gtypar,p3gty,p3gtygnm,p9gtypar,p9gty,p9gtygnm,nagtypar,nagty,nagtygnm) values (5352,'2015-12-31',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
21:46:04.811 [AsyncExecutor.default-16] DEBUG slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.benchmark - Execution of prepared statement took 43µs
21:46:04.811 [AsyncExecutor.default-16] DEBUG slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - 1 rows affected
21:46:04.811 [main] DEBUG slick.backend.DatabaseComponent.action - #1: [fused] asTry
```

There's no lockback file in Scala standalone. How to change logging options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following dependency in `build.sbt`

`"org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % “1.6.4"`

And add slick logger setting which is below to `logback.xml`

`<logger name="slick.jdbc" level="ERROR" />`

Comment: The `logback.xml` file should be created in `src/main/resources` as this is a standalone Play application